# Can you use redux toolkit's enchancedEndpoints for code splitting?

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

In their [docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/code-splitting) they have `injectEndpoints` and `enhancedEndpoints` in their code splitting section. However the `enhancedEndpoints` does not directly state it is used for code splitting. Just that it merges changes in differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enhanceEndpoints` is for changing existing endpoints. `injectEndpoints` is for adding new endpoints. So usually you would use `injectEndpoints` for code splitting, since you want to add new endpoints.